# How to connect pgAdmin->AWS RDS PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I have AWS RDS PostgreSQL database and try to connect from pgAdmin on my local machine to this database. It writes:
Internal server error: unable to connect to server? timeout expired.

Here are my rules

```
GroupId,GroupName,Type,IpProtocol,FromPort,ToPort,IpRanges,Ipv6Ranges,PrefixListIds,UserIdGroupPairs
sg-065*17,default,Inbound/Ingress,'-1,,,0.0.0.0/0,,,
sg-065*17,default,Inbound/Ingress,'-1,,,,::/0,,
sg-065*17,default,Inbound/Ingress,'-1,,,,,,sg-065*17
sg-065*17,default,Outbound/Egress,'-1,,,0.0.0.0/0,,,
```

What to check?

Comment: Check if your RDS instance is configured to generate a public IP. If it doesn't you can only connect to it through your amazon VPC

Comment: Where can i check it?

Comment: In your AWS console if you find your database (under RDS) it should say in "Security" something like "Publicly accessible"

Comment: I used this article to create [PostgreSQL instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.PostgreSQL.html), You need to change parameter ''Publicly accessible" in settings to allow connection from your local computer.